# Storing Object Reference in Hash Key Value (In difference Class) And To Invoke Method

Tags: perl

```
filename : Frames.pm
```

Below Class if the one which hosts / provide method for end user.

```
BEGIN
{
          require Exporter;
          our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
          our @EXPORT_OK =  qw();
          our @EXPORT =  qw(print_me);

 }

 package Frames;

 sub new
 {
     my ($clsname,$self) = @_;
     $self = {};
     bless $self,$clsname;
     return $self;
 }

 sub print_me
 { 
      print "Testing my Frame Object Reference call";
 } 

  1;

 Filename = Testing.pm
```

This Class is the one, which hold the reference of frame Class object in hash key value pair. I was trying to invoke methof based on this hash value.

```
 package Test;

 sub new
 {
        my ($clsname,$frame_ref) = @_;
        my $self = { frame => $frame_ref };   
        # here storing frame     reference as value not key
        bless $self,$clsname;
        return $self;
 }

 sub test_call
 {
        my ($self) = shift;
        ## invoking object reference based method

        %{$self->{frame}}->print_me;

        ## Above method call is failing
  }

  Filename Test.pl

  use Frames;

  my $frobj = Frames->new;
  my $testobj = Test->new($frobj); 
  # Frame object passed

  $testobj->test_call;
```

Frames is the Class, which hosts/provides some method
Test is the class which hold object of frame
I was looking to call that object of frame through Test class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying too hard. The left-hand side of `->` should be the reference to the object, and you stored that reference in `$self->{frame}` (not `%{$self->{frame}}`).

```
sub test_call
{
    my ($self) = shift;
    ## invoking object reference based method

    $self->{frame}->print_me;

    ## Above method call will now work.
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, yeah true. Its works like charm now.
Another quick question, apologies for asking

Every class we usually return hash anonmouns class reference, Is it possible to return Class reference as array ?

Comment: @pavan_843 objects can be any type of reference

Comment: @ysth - can you provide sample code snippet to give array reference as object. Thanking you in advance

Comment: That nomenclature isn't correct. The reference isn't the object; that which is referenced is the object. So, it would be more appropriate to say "Objects can be any type of *variable*."

Comment: The following creates an array-based object: `sub new { bless([], $_[0]) }`. Since methods are invoked via a reference to the object, nothing changes on the outside. It's `$o->method` whether `$o` references an array object or a hash object.

Comment: Check out [Mojo::Collection](https://metacpan.org/source/SRI/Mojolicious-8.10/lib/Mojo/Collection.pm#L55-58) and [Mojo::ByteStream](https://metacpan.org/source/SRI/Mojolicious-8.10/lib/Mojo/ByteStream.pm#L34-37) for examples of arrayref and scalarref based object classes. Though unlike most objects, these are designed for their underlying structure to be accessed directly.

Comment: @ikegami: According to the perlfunc man page and my own experience, bless only works on refs.  Also, I've had a single variable with three different references to it each blessed to a different package, and I get an error if I try to bless a scalar.  So I think ysth was correct.

Comment: @EdGrimm, `bless` takes a ref, but that didn't contradict anything I said. You're wrong about the reference being blessed, though. You mention `bless`'s entry in perlfunc, but you obviously didn't consult it: "*This function tells the thingy referenced by REF that it is now an object in the CLASSNAME package.*"

Comment: @ikegami: What I failed to do at way too early in the morning as I was taking a break from trying and failing to sleep was to re-test what I remembered working in the past.  If I could bless multiple references to the same thing as different classes, that would show the situation conclusively.  While I remember having done that at one point, I can't with my current perl.  Which conclusively says you and the docs are right.

Comment: @Ed Grimm, Aside from using Devel::Peek, you can also prove what the docs and I say using `perl -e'sub foo { } $o = bless({}); (\%$o)->foo'` and `perl -e'sub foo { } bless \%o; (\%o)->foo'`. This has been the case since at least 5.6